# jmeter remote testing - IP address

Tags: jmeter, remote-server

Is it possible to configure which IP address should jmeter-server use?

We have 1 Windows jMeter client server and 2 Linux jMeter server.

```
Windows:
User-IP 44.44.44.110
Backup-IP 180.110.110.10

Linux 1:
User-IP 44.44.44.111
Backup-IP 180.110.110.11

Linux 2:
User-IP 44.44.44.112
Backup-IP 180.110.110.12
```

I send execution of test to the slaves on IPs: 44.44.44.111 and 44.44.44.112, but slaves try to send me results back on IPs 180.110.110.11 and 180.110.110.12.

I get an Error:

```
2017/11/03 22:18:09 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 180.110.110.10; nested exception is: 
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Backup-IP communication is forbidden, so I have to use only User-IP. How to hande this?

still the same problem.

```
root@slave02jm:/usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin : ps -ef | grep jmeter
root     31350 30659  0 09:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./jmeter-server
root     31352 31350  0 09:38 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=44.44.44.112 -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log
root     31381 31352  9 09:38 pts/0    00:00:00 java -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms1024m -Xmx6144m -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=44.44.44.112 -Dserver_port=1099 -s -j jmeter-server.log
```

log

```
    2017/11/04 09:38:23 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/user.properties 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/system.properties 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting System property: java.rmi.server.hostname=44.44.44.112 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting System property: server_port=1099 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2016 The Apache Software Foundation 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 3.0 r1743807 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_102 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=3.0.101-108.10-default 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Max memory     =5726797824 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Available Processors =4 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 44.44.44.112 Name: slave02 FullName: slave02 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Starting backing engine on 1099 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Resolving by name the value of System property 'java.rmi.server.hostname':44.44.44.112 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Local IP address=44.44.44.112 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating RMI registry (server.rmi.create=true) 
2017/11/04 09:38:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Bound to registry on port 1099 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET] 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2017/11/04 09:38:57 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Creating JMeter engine on host slave02 base '.' 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Remote client host: 44.44.44.110 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/usr/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin' 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='.' 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Applying properties {} 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl: Running test 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2017/11/04 09:39:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2017/11/04 09:39:03 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 180.110.110.10; nested exception is: 
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:130)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.testStarted(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:85)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:205)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:324)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 10 more
```

do you see any problem?

Thanks for your help.

s.

Comment: Any feedback on answer , if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that others can trust it? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

configuration setting in system.properties (jmeter Windows client) do the trick java.rmi.server.hostname=44.44.44.110

Comment: Would have been better instead of copying original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105468/460802, to accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

When starting the jmeter-server ensure you add

> -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=Internal_IP

This will do what you want